# DOM Exception 5 INVALID CHARACTER error on valid base64 image string in javascript

Tags: javascript, image, base64, decode

I'm trying to decode a base64 string for an image back into binary so it can be downloaded and displayed locally by an OS.

The string I have successfully renders when put as the src of an HTML IMG element with the data URI preface (data: img/png;base64,   ) but when using the atob function or a goog closure function it fails.

However decoding succeeds when put in here: http://www.base64decode.org/

Any ideas?

EDIT: 
I successfully got it to decode with another library other than the built-in JS function. But, it still won't open locally - on a Mac says it's damaged or in an unknown format and can't get opened.

The code is just something like:

```
imgEl.src = 'data:img/png;base64,' + contentStr; //this displays successfully
decodedStr = window.atob(contentStr); //this throws the invalid char exception but i just
//used a different script to get it decode successfully but still won't display locally
```

the base64 string itself is too long to display here (limit is 30,000 characters)

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I was just banging my head against the wall on this one for awhile.

There are a couple of possible causes to the problem.  1)  Utf-8 problems.  There's a good write up + a solution for that [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20200220161900/http://monsur.hossa.in:80/2012/07/20/utf-8-in-javascript.html).

In my case, I also had to make sure all the whitespace was out of the string before passing it to atob.  e.g.

```
function decodeFromBase64(input) {
  input = input.replace(/\s/g, '');
  return atob(input);
}
```

What was really frustrating was that the base64 parsed correctly using the base64 library in python, but not in JS.

Comment: Thanks ! It is a life saver. I had a ridiculously long PDF in Base64, and it was creating error in mobile application but was working in web browser. Removing spaces did work.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I had a similar problem but it was a trailing carriage return that was only showing up in Safari.  This same methodology fixed it.

Comment: Rails apparently chops base64 pretty frequently, and Chrome will ignore the  whitespace while Safari won't. Your `replace` suggestion got my app working on Safari again. Thanks for this!

Comment: Huge help. Couldn't figure out why my atob worked in Chrome and FF but not IE. Took way too long to find this. : )

Comment: Thanks, it's a life saver.

Answer (score 3):

I had to remove the `data:audio/wav;base64,` in front of the b64, as this was given as part of the b64.

`var data = b64Data.substring(b64Data.indexOf(',')+1);`

`var processed = atob(data);`