# Transfer image from firebase storage to firebase database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase

I have a profile picture stored in my firebase storage for each user. Here is the reference:

```
profilePicRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser.uid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")
```

I want to be able to access the picture from my storage and put it into my database using this path:

```
@IBAction func Post(_ sender: AnyObject) {

   let postObject: Dictionary<String, Any> = [

         "userpic" : ""
    ]

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("posts").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).childByAutoId().setValue(postObject)

 }
```

I am unclear as to what goes into the quotation marks next to "userpic"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database itself is not ideal for storing photos (however you could technically do a [base64 encoding of an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352884/save-base64-encoded-image-to-firebase-storage), which might be better if the images are very small).

What I've found works best for profile images is to store them Firebase storage based on the UID.  When I want to upload an image, I resize it first:

```
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/29138120/1822214.  Only for square images.
func resizeWith(_ width: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: width, height: CGFloat(ceil(width/size.width * size.height)))))
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.image = self
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageView.bounds.size, false, scale)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return nil }
    imageView.layer.render(in: context)
    guard let result = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else { return nil }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return result
}
```

and then I upload it like so:

```
    func uploadProfilePic(_ uid: String, image: UIImage?, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ())
        // compress with moderate quality (between 0 and 1)
        let data: Data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.5)!
        let profileRef = storageRef.child("users/\(uid)/profile.jpg")

        let metadata = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metadata.contentType = "image/jpg"

        // Upload the file
        let uploadTask = profileRef.put(data, metadata: metadata) { metadata, error in
            if (error != nil) {
                // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
                print("there was an error uploading the profile pic!")
                print(error)
                // completion with failure... :(
                completion(false)
            } else {
                // Metadata contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                let downloadURL = metadata!.downloadURL
                // completion with success!
                completion?(true)
            }
        }
    }
```

I hope this can get you started, let me know if you've got any questions.