# How can I get the base64 of a file uploaded to Firebase Storage from Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I'm being passed a URL to a Firebase storage file in Cloud Functions, and need to take that URL and get a base64 string from it.

I was using request is taking too long and causing errors, so I'd rather parse the URL, get the file in Firebase storage, and get the base64 string from there.

I tried using admin.storage() but cannot .refFromURL() from there, or fetch the file. It is in nested subdirectories, which I can provide during parsing the URL.

How can I do this?

```
const passedURL = 'https://{FIREBASESTORAGEPROJECT}.googleapis.com/v0/b/{BUCKET}.appspot.com/o/{FOLDER_NAME_1}/{FOLDER_NAME_2}/{DOCUMENT_NAME}.{EXT}'
admin.storage().refFromURL(passedURL) // not a function
```

Comment: Why are you using base64?

Comment: Need to pass it to the DocuSign API as an additional document

Comment: Were you by chance just asking about this the other day?  I just read another question the other day about someone wanting to add a document via the DocuSign API.  I remember looking it up and seeing that the document could be posted separately.  Remember, you're adding 33% overhead and wasting memory and CPU by doing this via base64.

Comment: Not sure but this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37352884/save-base64-encoded-image-to-firebase-storage could be helpful for you

Comment: @Brad that wasn't me-- what is the more efficient way to add a pdf to a Docusign envelope? Only seeing information about adding via documentBase64

Comment: @SamuelRomero Thank you-- I need to use admin though since I am working in node/Firebase Cloud Functions